# How to test TV LED backlight failure

Tags: led, led-strip, tv, backlight

I recently picked up a Braum (Aldi) TV from the nature strip to play around with.
The TV seems to work perfectly fine (Channels, DVD input, sound etc) except that there's no working backlight.

I've proceeded to disassemble the TV, and found there is 9 lights x 3 strips = 27 backlights.
Each strip seems to have an identifier "94V-0 E348124". The product number for the strip: K395A0835350309686-Rev1.1 I. Looking online it seems to match a Sceptre LED backstrip.

I assume the 94V is referring to the forward voltage required to switch on the LEDS? I think the LEDs seem to be in series, so is the voltage roughly 10.5 V required per LED? (Or would it be 3.5V, assuming 3 strips?) If they are in series, if one fails they'll all fail right (hence 0% backlight)? I can see two pin contacts to test each LED which is nice.

What equipment should I use to go about testing the strips? I don't believe I have any equipment that can supply 10.5V, and haven't really done anything like this before. From looking at other  forums it seems that a common TV backlit LED runs with >3V and about 150mA. Looking for an inexpensive option.

Comment: 2 nine volt batteries and a resistor in series (say, 1K) would be a pretty cheap option to test each led individually.

Comment: yup, and you won't need very many mA to see if it works, probably. Those things are blindingly bright at their rated current.

Comment: The 94V is in reference to the PCB material flame rating, not voltage.

Comment: You should add pictures of the LEDs and if visible, their wiring, to help narrow it down.  Your question might be taken down as there is a skill/effort requirement for repair questions.  Take the tour in the bottom left for clarification.

Comment: 3V diodes are more likely in a device such as a TV using a switch mode converter and constant current driver.  9V and higher are more commonly used in inexpensive lighting driven directly off of rectified mains voltage.  Should be easy enough to test if the array has gone open circuit due to a burned out diode.

Comment: Learn the basics about how to measure a supply voltage and test LED’s before guessing, get the manuals for service

Comment: Yep exactly the same considerations as discussed above, in that question. Thanks all for the clarifications.